# Issue while executing " npm start" command

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on Frontend side Project. I create React_app and after that I run the 'npm start' command it returns an error. The error is as follows.

```
    (hello) D:\NewPython\DockerDjangoReactProject\frontend\react_app>npm start

> react_app@0.1.0 start D:\NewPython\DockerDjangoReactProject\frontend\react_app
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-01T05_06_13_740Z-debug.log
```

please help me solve this problem, I want to complete my project but this error is in my way.

Comment: Please post the github repo

Comment: Might it be the react-scripts package isn't installed?

Comment: @FLiotta yes right After that i run npm start it will gives me this error

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/reportWebVitals.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'web-vitals' in 'D:\NewPython\DockerDjangoReactProject\frontend\react_app\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.      -- On browser

Comment: Did you tried remove node_modules directory and re-install dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with `react-scripts`. Possibilities are

1. `react-scripts` is not installed. In this case, you can manually install using this command.

`npm install react-scripts --save`

2. Or if it is already there, then it might be the problem with `node_modules` folder. You can remove this folder and/or run the following command.

`npm install`

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for yor response! @Ankita